# Cant able to export mysql data to godaddy server - showing syntax error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

This is my procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `RPTtempreceipts`(
IN vRCPTNO VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
DECLARE vBNo VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE vPtyCde INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE vWMC VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE vPrdCde VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE vBcde CHAR(5);
DECLARE vSAPLID INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

-- Assign Values
SELECT T.BNo,T.pty_code,T.WMC,T.PrdCde,T.Bcde INTO 
vBNo,vPtyCde,vWMC,vPrdCde,vBcde FROM
tbltransaction T INNER JOIN tbltransreceipts TR
ON T.BNo=TR.BNo WHERE TR.RcptNO=vRCPTNO;

SELECT SAPLID INTO vSAPLID FROM tblcust_prd_wor WHERE pty_code=vPtyCde;

-- Select Queries are configured as for Typed Dataset under DT's
SELECT * FROM tbltrans WHERE BNo=vBNo;
SELECT * FROM tbltransrcpt WHERE RNo=vRCPTNO;
END
```

Showing following error:

> Error Code : 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'DECLARE vPtyCde INTEGER' at line 1 (328 ms taken)
>
> Error Code : 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'DECLARE vWMC VARCHAR(20)' at line 1 (312 ms taken)
>
> Error Code : 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'DECLARE vPrdCde VARCHAR(10)' at line 1 (328 ms
>   taken)
>
> Error Code : 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'DECLARE vBcde CHAR(5)' at line 1 (313 ms taken)
>
> Error Code : 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'DECLARE vSAPLID INTEGER DEFAULT 0' at line 1 (297
>   ms taken)
>
> Error Code : 1327 Undeclared variable: vBNo (312 ms taken)
>
> Error Code : 1327 Undeclared variable: vSAPLID (297 ms taken)

I am confused with this because its working fine in localhost.
now i finished the project and like to upload the db to server.
But these errors stopped me to proceed further... Please help me.

Regards,
Sensa.

Comment: Aren't MySql vars prefixed with '@'? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html

Comment: Is it required to have this line: CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`

may i delete this "DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`"
and just keep CREATE

Comment: The problem is with DEFINER. DEFINER CLASS is handling previledges. So, please let me know how to remove DEFINER in stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is splitting your input into separate queries after each `;`.

This post explains how to avoid that: http://blog.nth-design.com/2009/02/25/creating-sp-in-phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 0):

As DCoder said, the delimiter you are using ";" is causing the issue.  You will need to change your delimiter to something taht does not appear anywhere in your query. The example of '$$' in the blog post would most likely be safe as a double dollar sign is not likely to show up in many places.

You need to ensure your database is a 5.0 or higher MySQL database as procedures only started in 5.0.

Also, the define root@localhost is not going to work of Go Daddy shared hosting.  You should be able to get rid of that section or use dbuser@'%'.